# Manipulating expressions for use in 'odefun' in ODE solvers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have a system of second order differential equations that I want to solve, which I have in symbolic form using variables y1, dy1, etc. For example:

```
dy1 = y1 + y2
dy2 = 2*y1 + y2^3
```

In order to use an ODE solver from Matlab, I need an 'odefun' where I express the system of first-order differential equations in a form similar to:

```
function dydt = eqs(t,y)
dydt = [y(1)+y(2);   2*y(1)+y(2)^3]
```

Now, in my problem at hand, the symbolic equations are way too long and can't even be properly shown in the screen:

```
dy1 = y1 + y2 + ... More than 25000 characters
dy2 = 2*y1 + y2^3 + ... More than 25000 characters
```

So in order to write the corresponding function to use in the ODE solver, i would need to type something similar to the following:

```
function dydt = eqs(t,y)
dydt = [y(1)+y(2)+...More than 25000 characters; 2*y(1)+y(2)^3+...More than 25000 characters]
```

Evidently, not feasible. What I want is to manipulate the equations in symbolic form in order to substitute 'y1' with 'y(1)'. However, it does not seem straightforward because a variable can't have a name including parentheses, that is, syms y(1) gives error.

Another approach: If the original symbolic equations are constructed using strings, then it is possible to substitute the strings 'y1' for 'y(1)'. Afterwards, I could copy the expressions in a Matlab script file where I define the function dydt. However, the expressions are too long to be shown completely, whether symbolic or strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily define an inline function (aka: function handle) like this:

`dydt=@(y) [ sum(y) ; 2y(1)+y(2)^3+...]`

Then you can enter any arbitrary values with `dydt(y)`.

You can also use it in `ode45()` function as an input for solving the differential equation.

Comment: I don't get how does that help my problem at hand. In order to define the inline function, I need to write expressions with y(1), y(2), etc. I have the symbolic expressions using y1, y2, etc. but it is way too long (and can't even be fully shown, since it has 25k+ characters) to manually change it to y(1), y(2).